# What causes this weird vertical line glitch on this website in Chrome 76?

Tags: google-chrome

I came across the below glitch on https://www.troyhunt.com/, while randomly reading one of his articles:

[image]

As you can see, a weird set of vertical black bars appears on his navigational menu when I hover over my browser tabs. This bug occurs regardless of window size, regardless of which page of his blog I'm on, regardless of whether it is the only tab in the window (though it's less visible if it's one tab), regardless of where I enter the tab list. It persists through tab closes and reopenings, refreshes and chrome restarts. There is nothing in the Javascript console logs, and it doesn't happen on Firefox or Edge.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this? I'm using Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10 1903.

Comment: I've given this a shot on vivaldi - which uses the blink engine, and no repro - so chances are its probably not the website.

Comment: Looks like drop shadows for something. Anyway, can reproduce, most certainly a Chrome bug.

Comment: Caused by `backdrop-filter: blur(5px);` on the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that this has been resolved in Chrome 79.

---

This is a known bug for the CSS property `backdrop-filter`. It has been reported to the Chromium development team [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=986206). There is not currently a workaround.

My research suggests that this is a new CSS property that has only just been added to [Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) in this version.